# Very Slow Magento 2 in windows subsystem for Linux(WSL )

Tags: magento2, installation, windows, windows10

I have installed Magento 2 inside WSL ubuntu 20 for local development, but the speed is very slow.
Cache is enabled and store mode is default.
Anyone experiences the same issue.
My system configuration is
Core i5 2.3
RAM 8 GB
SSD: 250 GB

Comment: WIndows could never able to give you performance as a real linux.

Comment: But it should be better than XAMP, I thought it will be a good alternative as compared to XAMP, but seems extremely slow. Tried many docker images for Magento still docker is also slow.

Comment: XAMPP can work faster than docker instance. Best way for developer magento projects is using Linux :(

Answer (score 0):

One of my dev environments for Magento 2 is an old laptop running Ubuntu host and Docker containers in a Windows VMWare environment:

- Core i7 2.3
- 8 GB RAM

It is workable, but slow compared to bare metal server in production.

I imagine using WSL as the virtual environment will be as slow as a week in jail...